# Communicate between Service and a Class

Tags: java, android, service

In my MainActivity I use

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, myService.class);
bindService(serviceIntent,serviceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

to create a blutetooth connection service, if `is.connect()` returns true I want to pass a variable from the service to a separate class without using a broadcaster. If I create `CheckIfConnected()` int service how do I call it from a separate class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to communicate seamlessly and without tightly coupling your application code, try using `events`. My favorite is `EventBus - android library`. Here is how you can do this:

Add this to your `build.gradle` file (module-level)

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Next, create a `Plain Old Java Object` (POJO) to represent your event!

```
public class ServiceConnectedEvent{
   private boolean isServiceConnected;

   ServiceConnectedEvent(boolean isConnected){
      this.isServiceConnected = isConnected;
   }

   public boolean isServiceConnected{
      return this.isServiceConnected;
   }
}
```

Next, in your service, which will act as the `publisher`, post an event like this:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new ServiceConnectedEvent(true));
```

Now, in the class that you want to notify of service connection status, you can register it to make it a `subscriber` like this:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

To actually get the notification in your class, add this method:

```
public void onEvent(ServiceConnectedEvent event){
   if(event.isServiceConnected()){
      //do what you need when service is connected
   }
}
```

Remember, you can pass back anything you want like a variable of your choice!

If you are inside an activity or fragment, you can `unregister` the event inside `onDestroy`:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
   super.onDestroy();

   EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

This should make your communication between your service and any other class easy!!

I hope you get it working - good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a callback method. 
You could create your own Intent class which extends it but possesses an interface which contains the method you would like to call. Then you could override the `connect()` method which would then call this interface method before returning `true`. Then you would have to make your separate class implement your `CustomIntent.ConnectInterface` and make it override your interface method.
I think that would likely work if I understand your problem correctly.

```
public class CustomIntent extends Intent {
   public interface ConnectInterface {
      public void connectInterfaceCallback();
   }
   private ConnectInterface callback; 
   public CustomIntent(ConnectInterface callback){
      super();
      this.callback = callback;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean connect() {
      if(super.connect()){
         callback.connectInterfaceCallback();
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

And then :

```
public class SeparateClass implements CustomIntent.ConnectInterface {
   ...
   @Override
   public void connectInterfaceCallback() {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Edited it with a small example illustrating what I was trying to say.